# 'Invalid type comparison' in the code

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a `pandas dataframe` which has many columns. These columns may have 3 values - True, False and NaN. I'm replcaing the `NaN` with the string `missing`. The sample values for one of my columns is as follows:

```
ConceptTemp.ix[:,1].values
```

resulting in:

```
array([ True, False, False, False,  True,  True,  True,  True, False,  True], dtype=bool)
```

Note that this particular column had no `NaN`, and therefore no `missing` string.

Now I execute the following code:

```
ConceptTemp.ix[:,1][ConceptTemp.ix[:,1] != 'missing'].values
```

To get the following exception:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-47-0a0b76cf3ab5> in <module>()
----> 1 ConceptTemp.ix[:,1][ConceptTemp.ix[:,1] != 'missing'].values

E:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops.pyc in wrapper(self, other, axis)
    724                 other = np.asarray(other)
    725 
--> 726             res = na_op(values, other)
    727             if isscalar(res):
    728                 raise TypeError('Could not compare %s type with Series'

E:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops.pyc in na_op(x, y)
    680                 result = getattr(x, name)(y)
    681                 if result is NotImplemented:
--> 682                     raise TypeError("invalid type comparison")
    683             except AttributeError:
    684                 result = op(x, y)

TypeError: invalid type comparison
```

Would someone know how to fix it?

Any pointers would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Please print `ConceptTemp.ix[:, 1].values` and report back.

Comment: Perhaps not exactly what you are looking for but could you use `isin`?
`ConceptTemp.ix[:,0][~ConceptTemp.ix[:,0].isin(['missing'])].values`

Comment: I edited the comment you can use the `~` operator to invert the selection

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As people have commented, it is a bit weird to combine types in your arrays (i.e. strings with booleans). You're going to get results where the boolean array may not be what you think it is. But if you absolutely have to, there are a couple of ways you could go about doing this. The first is with `isin`:

```
In [40]: ConceptTemp.ix[:,0][~ConceptTemp.ix[:,0].isin(['missing'])].values
Out[40]:
         array([ True, False, False, False,  True,  True,  True,  True, False,  True], dtype=bool)
```

The second is with `apply` and `lambda`

```
In [41]: ConceptTemp.ix[:,0][ConceptTemp.ix[:,0].apply(lambda x: x != 'missing')].values
Out[41]:
         array([ True, False, False, False,  True,  True,  True,  True, False,  True], dtype=bool)
```

Comment: Thanks so much. The `lambda` did it. I agree that it's a little awkward, this type comparison. But I was only doing it coz I wanted the subset of my original `dataframe`.